# Spring MVC response takes too long

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple controller method that calls a spring data repository and returns a few objects.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/api/learnitemlists", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<LearnItemList>> getLearnItemLists(@RequestParam(value="fromLanguages") Optional<List<String>> fromLanguages, 
                                                                @RequestParam(value="toLanguage") Optional<String> toLanguage,
                                                                @RequestParam("pagenumber") Integer pageNumber, 
                                                                @RequestParam("pagesize") Integer pageSize) {
    LOGGER.debug("start of learnItemLists call");

    Page<LearnItemList> lists;
    lists = learnItemListRepositoryCustom.findBasedOnLanguage(fromLanguages,toLanguage,new PageRequest(pageNumber,pageSize));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("X-total-count", Long.toString(lists.getTotalElements()));
    headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-total-count");

    ResponseEntity<Iterable<LearnItemList>> result = new ResponseEntity<Iterable<LearnItemList>>(lists,headers,HttpStatus.OK);

    LOGGER.debug("end of learnItemLists call");

    return result;
}
```

I logged the beginning and the end of the method call:
22:06:11.914 - 22:06:12.541 
So the actual retrieval of objects from the database is well under 1 second. However, the full request took about 2.68 when trying in a browser (integration tests show similar performance).

I can't help but think that something is off. Can serialization into JSON (I'm using Jackson) take this long? The whole JSON response is about 1 kb...

So is this normal (I doubt it), and if not, what steps should I take to find out the cause?

Comment: Serializing json can take a while depending on somet things. Your database fetch is probably lazily pulling objects, the json serialization is then loading each field from the database. You may see different performance with eager loading if that's the issue.

Comment: Are you using JPA for learnItemListRepositoryCustom? and can I ask what inteface is learnItemListRepositoryCustom implementing? 

With JPA @Entity I have been bitten by this FetchTpye=LAZY vs EGAR latency.

Also, nearly forgot are you using a caching mechanism? e.g. Ehcache?